# String comparison yields bad results

Tags: string, arduino, serial-port, comparison

I read from my serial and print to make sure entries are correct. When `"red"` `"green"` or `"blue"` (typed without the quotes) none of the comparisons work. The printed line shows the correct color. Hardware all checks with the last `else` flashing the colors correctly.

I tried `if (myColor == "red")` and `if (myColor.equals("red")` and none of the colors work.

I substituted `String x="red"` and then `if (x.equals("red"))` and it works as expected. I know that the problem is with the Serial reading to `myColor`. I just can't figure out how to make it work.

Code:

```cpp
int redPin=8;
int greenPin=9;
int bluePin=10;

String myColor;
String msg="What color do you want? ";

void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(bluePin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(greenPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    Serial.println(msg);

    while (Serial.available()==0){
    }

    myColor=Serial.readString();
    Serial.println(myColor); //check to see that it was entered correctly

    if (myColor == "red"){
        digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
        digitalWrite(bluePin, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(greenPin, LOW);
    }
    else if (myColor == "green"){
        digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
        digitalWrite(bluePin, LOW);
        digitalWrite(greenPin, HIGH);
    }
    else if (myColor == "blue"){
        digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
        digitalWrite(bluePin, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(greenPin, LOW);
    }
    else {
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
            digitalWrite(redPin, HIGH);
            delay (500);
            digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
            delay (500);
            digitalWrite(bluePin, HIGH);
            delay (500);
            digitalWrite(bluePin, LOW);
            delay (500);
            digitalWrite(greenPin, HIGH);
            delay (500);
            digitalWrite(greenPin, LOW);
            delay(500);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your checking code to be something like:

```
String x = String("[") + myColor + String("]");
Serial.println(x);
Serial.println(myColor.length());
```

There's a good chance that your string may have *other* stuff in it, such as a newline character or space. If it does, you'll see output like:

```
[red ]
[ red]
[red
]
```

rather than the single-line `[red]`. The second `println` is to output the length for verification as well, to ensure that `red` matches `3`, `blue` matches `4`, and so on.

---

And just two final things:

- I'd tend to turn off current outputs first before turning on the relevant one. It *may* not be necessary but it comes from being burnt by systems that don't like having multiple outputs on at the same time. That means, for blue, you would do something like the following, where the other two are first driven low, *then* blue is driven high:

  ```
  digitalWrite(redPin,   LOW);
  digitalWrite(greenPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(bluePin,  HIGH);
  ```
- Your code block for `red` is currently the same as `blue`, you probably should have this instead:

  ```
  digitalWrite(bluePin,  LOW);
  digitalWrite(greenPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(redPin,   HIGH);
  ```

---

On that first bullet point above, you could simplify your code with a little refactoring, such as introducing a function to do the selection of which pin is on:

```
void offOffOn(int offA, int offB, int on) {
    digitalWrite(offA, LOW);
    digitalWrite(offB, LOW);
    digitalWrite(on,   HIGH);
}
```

Then your `loop()` section becomes shorter (with a "compressed" `else` clause as well):

```
if (myColor == "red") {
    offOffOn(greenPin, bluePin, redPin);
} else if (myColor == "green") {
    offOffOn(redPin, bluePin, greenPin);
} else if (myColor == "blue") {
    offOffOn(redPin, greenPin, bluePin);
} else {
    int allPins[] = { redPin, bluePin, greenPin };
    size_t pinCount = sizeof(allPins) / sizeof(*allPins);
    for (int count = 0; count < pinCount * 3; ++count) {
        digitalWrite(allPins[idx % pinCount], HIGH); delay (500);
        digitalWrite(allPins[idx % pinCount], LOW);  delay (500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct - I discovered each string length was 1 more than expected and a myColor.trim() before the conditionals fixed the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[`readString`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ReadString) is an awful function that shouldn't be used.
It makes the code run slow (slow to repond) and delimits messages by time.
By default, it waits 1 second for no data to arrive, before it returns. After that it returns everything that was sent.

If you send lines `"red"` and `"green"` one after another, `myColor` will be `"red\ngreen\n"`, unless you do it slowly with more than 1 second gap.
Even if you receive a single line, there will still be a trailing new-line character at the end.

You should use [`readStringUntil`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ReadStringUntil):

```
myColor = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
```

It will make your code a lot more responsive and it returns the line without the new-line character.
Just make sure that the Serial monitor only sends a new-line character ("Newline" option).